# vertex_ids table missing in cassandra under the janusgraph keyspace?

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph

Titan graph when used with cassandra creates a table "vertex_ids" under the "titan" keyspace. But when working with janus , I can't seem to find the "vertex_ids" table under the 'janusgrpah' keyspace. Also I read the documentation where they describe how the values are stored but it doesn't tell under which tables.

Comment: Which version of Titan did you use ?

Answer (score 3):

JanusGraph started from TitanDB 1.0.0. Both are using these below cassandra tables :

- edgestore : Store Vertex, Property and Edges as Adjacency List
- graphindex : Builtin indexes for vertex and edge properties
- titan_ids (TitanDB) janusgraph_ids (JanusGraph) : Store ID Block
- txlog : Store Transaction Log
- systemlog : Store System Log
- system_properties : Store System Properties
- edgestore_lock_ : Used to lock edgestore table
- graphindex_lock_ : Used to lock graphindex table
- system_properties_lock_ : Used to lock system_properties table