# add vertex to dynamodb using DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, gremlin, titan

I build Amazon DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan.

I used this for build the env - based on template.
After the resource was created I saw the dynamodb was created based on `dynamodb.properties` file.

[image]

After the resource was created, I open ssh to Linux EC2 and start `bin/gremlin.sh.`

I wish to add data to dynamo, so I tried to add vertex by folliwing commands:

```
    gremlin> bin/gremlin.sh
    gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
    gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open("/usr/local/packages/dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend-1.0.0-hadoop1/conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb.properties")

gremlin> g.addVertex('date_of_birth').property('date_of_birth','1949-01-01')
vp[date_of_birth->1949-01-01]
```

but now when I examine my dynamodb table, I see **titan_ids was changed**, but the data is not clear to read.
The `'v'` column is still EMPTY, **and not contain the vertex property.**

How can I solve that issue and see the vertex property in `v` column?

[image]

Comment: Titan Store data in binary format. So you can't read data directly. You have to decode it.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam how can I retrieve the vertex details by gremlin command?

Comment: Try `g.V().valueMap()`

Comment: @AshrafulIslam not working.., it said No signature of method StandardTitanGraph.V() is applicable for argument types: () value: []

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titan Store data in binary format in the storage backend. So you should use gremlin query.

- To get all the vertex and it's properties :

Example :

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[marko],age:[29]]
==>[name:[vadas],age:[27]]
==>[name:[lop],lang:[java]]
==>[name:[josh],age:[32]]
==>[name:[ripple],lang:[java]]
==>[name:[peter],age:[35]]
```

Comment: it work!, I got all vertexs, I dont still why the 'V' column is empty. Can you send me link to info How can I add edge between vertexs?

Comment: @maz Titan uses `titan_ids` table to generate unique id and the v column of the table not used, that's why it's empty

Comment: And by the way if it work, you can mark the answer as accept so that user user may find it useful

Comment: ok, will mark it,  which table and column the vertex properties are actually stored?

Comment: edgestore table used to store adjacency list and properties

Comment: Read this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414458/2320144

Comment: So, after reading the docs, why when I added vertex by: g.addVertex('new_vertex').property('new_vertex','1949-01-01') , I did not see change at edge_store, row only added to titan_id?Is the new vertex property need to be added in edge_store table?

Comment: Both table `titan_ids` and `edgestore` should be changed. after commit

Comment: after run the command: graph.addVertex('new_vertex').property('new_vertex','1949-01-01'‌​)  only titan_ids was changed, when I run yours commands : g = graph.traversal() ,  g.V().valueMap() I got the new vertex in output but only titan_ids table was changed, Have any idea?

Comment: Both should change, try to refresh and check the data again